# Accessing dynamically generated controls Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net

I am adding controls dynamically to my page on the basis on a condition.There's a button in these controls, to which i have attached an event handler as well for click event.Now in this event handler, i am trying to access my dynamically generated controls, but getting an exception. Here's my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String Method = Request.QueryString["Method"];
            String Tag = Request.QueryString["Tag"];


            if (Method=="ADD" && Tag=="METHOD")
            {

                //6
            TableCell cell11 = new TableCell();
            cell11.Text = "NEXTLEVEL";

            TableCell cell12 = new TableCell();
            TextBox txt6 = new TextBox();
            txt6.ID = "txt6";
            cell12.Controls.Add(txt6);

            TableRow row6 = new TableRow();
            row6.Cells.Add(cell11);
            row6.Cells.Add(cell12);

            container.Rows.Add(row6);
                TableCell cell14 = new TableCell();
                Button submit = new Button();
                submit.ID = "SubmitButton";
                submit.Text = "Submit";
                submit.Click += new EventHandler(submit_Click);

                cell14.Controls.Add(submit);

                TableRow row7 = new TableRow();

                row7.Cells.Add(cell14);

                container.Rows.Add(row7);
            }

void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ModifySessionAnalyzer msa = new ModifySessionAnalyzer();
            TextBox txt6= (TextBox)Page.FindControl("txt6") as TextBox;
            ##String message = txt6.Text;##

        }
```

Comment: You cannot access `txt6`? Where is textbox with this ID declared?

Comment: I have updated my code. I am able to access txt6 now in submit_click event handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TableCell cell12 = new TableCell();
TextBox txt6 = new TextBox();
txt6.ID = "txt6";
cell12.Controls.Add(new TextBox());
```

This is wrong, you are not adding the txt6 control to the cell, instead you are adding a new textBox...

Comment: Yea i did figure this out and modified the code as well.I am able to access dynamic controls now. I am confused on a statement here given by CrabBucket, saying i'd write my dynamically generated code in Page_Init rather than Page_load, i didn't get this. Why should i do this?

Comment: Because when you create the controls in the PageLoad, you lose the values defined by the user when a PostBack occurs. Good practice is to create the controls in the PageInit and load the values you need them to have in the PageLoad. When you have a postback, the controls get re-created in the PageInit and then .NET loads the ViewState data into the controls. I think this is not a problem anymore as of .NET 4, though. Will you accept my answer then? :)

Comment: @Dante. have you got a link/reference for the PageInit/PageLoad dynamic control creation issue not being an issue in .Net 4. Just interested. Thanks

Comment: Not really. In some other stackoverflow question about the same topic, it was mentioned that this was no longer an issue, but I didn't confirm it myself.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamically added controls should be added in the `Page_Init` method not `Page_Load`. If they are added into `Page_Load` they won't be added to the control tree and you'll get issues - i.e. they won't participate in ViewState correctly.

So `(TextBox)Page.FindControl("txt6")` could fail as the text box is no longer in the control tree

This could be the source of your issue.

**Further explanation**

Your code should be

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      //.. your code goes here
}
```

**NOT**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //.. your code
}
```

It's normal practice to use `Page_Load` so it's just an easy habit for people but when using dynamic controls then this is the exception

When i say dynamic controls - it's anything when you are added controls on the fly rather than declaring them in your page. Look for anything where you are going `Controls.Add`

Comment: I have updated the code, able to access the dynamically generated controls. I didn't get your point of adding them to page_init? Can you throw some more light.